# Regex.Matches using lookahead not getting any matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex

```
Regex.Matches(a, @"((?=.)\1+)")
```

The above regex should get matches without capturing pattern obliged results

But it does not fetch any matches

On the other hand when I use it without lookahead

like this

```
 Regex.Matches(a, @"(.)\1+")
```

It brings matches and working fine

I like to know why is this, why lookahead not fetching any matches.

My string is

```
   "zaaaaaaashjasjaaasjabbbajsljlsccccasjahsddddd";
```

the second line above brings

```
  [aaaaaaa],[aaa],...
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the lookahead is non-capturing, so the expression inside it has to contain a capture group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookahead neither does consume character nor capture it. Saying that, the back-reference `\1` in the first regex refers to nothing yet captured and makes total match to fail (this is not necessarily true in all regex flavors).

When the lookahead is within another capturing group the same statements apply. Lookahead doesn't consume anything so capturing group doesn't hold anything.

To capture whatever comes inside a lookahead (lookarounds generally) use capturing groups like this:

```
(?=(.))\1\1+
```

That is what you are trying to say with the first regular expression.